# How to get the next load of data inside jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am displaying SharePoint data inside a jQuery DataTables. The total number of rows is like 2000, but I am displaying only 100 on the first load.

When the page is loaded the **data is displayed correctly**. So, I wanted to get the next load of data inside the datatable, but I couldn't figure it out how to do that.

I thought of using `bServerSide` and `iDeferLoading` but these are giving me errors like the `json format is not correct`.

Below is my current code that I am testing at the moment. **Can anyone tell me how can I get the rest of the results?** How can I implement pagination when the user reaches the end of 100 rows?

Why `bServerSide` and `iDeferLoading` do not work in my case?

I have the same issue using jQuery and REST while doing a postback to SharePoint.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        window.StartTime = new Date();
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.search.js', 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery', function () {
                var queryText = "ContentTypeId:0x010066FA3DE3E334C841B418C82CC475A227*";
                var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(clientContext);
                keywordQuery.set_queryText(queryText);
                keywordQuery.set_rowLimit(50);
                keywordQuery.set_trimDuplicates(false);
                var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(clientContext);
                var results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryError);

                function onQuerySuccess() {

                    var rows = results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows;
                    var totalRows = results.m_value.ResultTables[0].TotalRows;

                    $("#example").DataTable({

                        "bDestory":true,
                        "bProcessing":true,
                        //"bServerSide": true,
                        "iTotalRecords":totalRows,
                        "iTotalDisplayRecords":10,
                        "iDeferLoading": totalRows,
                        "aaData":rows,
                        "aoColumns":[
                            {"mData":"Title"},
                            {"mData":"Path"}
                        ] 
                    }); 
                    console.log("After added to table: " + ((new Date() - window.StartTime) / (60 * 60)) + " seconds");

                }

                function onQueryError(sender, args) {
                    alert("call failed. Error: " + args.get_message());
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

This is the header response when I click on NEXT or dropdownlist when using `bServerSide` and `iDeferLoading` (Apparantly the `Content-Type` is returned as `text/html`):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
SPRequestGuid: 6fc9299d-cba4-c06b-92ee-423504bab93b
request-id: 6fc9299d-cba4-c06b-92ee-423504bab93b
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 84
SPIisLatency: 1
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4569
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 01 Sep 2015 19:37:35 GMT
Content-Length: 23942
```

How can I force it to return JSON formated data?

Answer (score 0):

Option `bServerSide` doesn't work for you because the data in the response has to be structured in a certain way, see [Server-side processing](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) (for DataTables 1.9) or [Server-side processing](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side) (for DataTables 1.10).

I would remove this line `keywordQuery.set_rowLimit(50);` if it limits number of results and let the DataTables do the filtering, sorting and pagination.

Also remove invalid or irrelevant options in your DataTables initialization codes, so it looks like:

```
var rows = results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows;

$("#example").DataTable({
     "aaData":rows,
     "aoColumns":[
         {"mData":"Title"},
         {"mData":"Path"}
     ] 
});
```